# Excel VBA moving Shapes to a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem with a program for my Excel VBA course. I have written a program to add 5 each of lines, rectangles, ovals and triangles to a worksheet this is the btnAddShapes click event. In the cmdAlignRectangles click event I am trying to take only the rectangles that were added and align them all in the C column. I have used a For Each loop to select all the shapes on the sheet, the For Each loop structure is required for the assignment. Then I used an If/Then statement to select the shape Type msoShapeRectangle. I used the name that I assigned in when creating the rectangles such as "Box1" using the counter I to iterate through each rectangle, it is this statement that is giving me an error saying that the item with that name was not found. I must use the *Left* property of the *Range* and *Shape* objects to move the rectangles.? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnAddShapes_Click()

Randomize
For I = 1 To 5    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 100, 100, 65).Select
    With Selection
        .Name = "Box" & I
        .Left = Int(422 * Rnd)
        .Top = Int(422 * Rnd)
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(10 + I * (Rnd * 133), 50 + I * (Rnd * 133), 125 + I * (Rnd * 133), 250 + I * (Rnd * 133)).Select
    With Selection
        .Name = "Line" & I
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 275, 240, 108, 44).Select
    With Selection
        .Name = "Oval" & I
        .Left = Int(444 * Rnd)
        .Top = Int(444 * Rnd)
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 514, 220, 93, 71).Select
    With Selection
        .Name = "Triangle" & I
        .Left = Int(377 * Rnd)
        .Top = Int(377 * Rnd)
    End With

Next I
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveShapes_Click()
Dim sh As Shape

For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not (sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Or sh.Type = msoFormControl Or sh.Type = msoTextBox) Then sh.Delete
Next sh

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAlignRectangles_Click()

Dim allRectangles As Shapes
Dim sh As Shape
Dim I As Integer

Set allRectangles = ActiveSheet.Shapes

I = 1

For Each sh In allRectangles
    If sh.Type = msoShapeRectangle Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Box" & I).Left = Cells(I, 3).Left
    End If
    I = I + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that in the creation loop you create 4 shapes for each 1, I going from 1 to 5. On the other hand, in the alignment loop you iterate one I for each shape. Therefore, when I reaches 6 (with the 6th shape), the object named "Box6" does not exist.

A simpler way to achieve this would be to modify our test by examining the name of the shape, like this, for example:

```
If sh.Type = msoShapeRectangle And InStr(sh.Name, "Box") = 1 Then
    sh.Left = Cells(I, 3).Left
End If
```

p.s. you can also drop the first part of the test

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!